# Array of parts with gschem and gnetlist

Tags: spice, geda

Anyone know how, or if it is even possible to create an array of parts/instances in **gschem** and netlist it with **gnetlist**. I'm trying `refdes=name<0:n>` and `refdes=name[0:n]` but gnetlist compains with:

```
Found unknown component.  Refdes = x<0:62>
Invalid refdes ('x<0:62>')
```

I would also like to do the same with nets. In addition, how would you concatenate arrays of nets/buses? For example `netname=a<5>,a<0:4>`.

Comment: Can you clarify a little? GSchem has a refdes renumbering tool which will follow an order (L->R or T->B, etc) so you can renumber all your "blocks" this way.

Comment: @kabZX In most schematic drawing programs you can draw a single symbol and name it X<1:n>. When you netlist the schematic this gets expanded, creating X1, X2, ..., XN. Same for the signals you connect to its ports. This allows for example instantiating and connecting hundreds of flip-flops or inverters in series, just by drawing one of them and naming it appropriately. My question is how to do this in gnetlist+gschem.